# Issues with $scope.$apply() in nested callbacks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Pretty new to Angular and trying to learn the best ways to have angular digest when changes are made outside of scope. Also please let me know if there is a better title to this issue.
     I have had quite a bit of luck on objects that change outside of scope but not on ones that are created outside of scope. Example below. I can register to changes on `$scope.sc.conversationManageger.conversations.added(conversation)` and in the callback I use `$scope.$apply();` and it updates the bindings as expected(or as I expected). However within that callback I register to another event `conversation.chatService.state.changed` on the `conversation` object that was passed from the previous callback. On this second callback I do get the event to fire and can confirm with `console.log(change)` however the `if (!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}` that I have in this second callback doesnt seem to update the bindings as it did on the original callback. I tried three different methods as shown in the code below but none of them seem to work. If I call `$scope.verify()` from a **ng-click** event though it updates with no issues.

```
$scope.sc = new Skype.Web.Model.Application;

$scope.sc.conversationsManager.conversations.added(function (conversation) {
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        //This Apply updates the objects as expected
        $scope.$apply();   

        conversation.chatService.state.changed(function (change) {
                //I do get the output in the console as expected so event does fire
                console.log(change)
                //Attempt 1, current Scope Apply doesnt update $scope.sc object
                if (!$scope.$$phase) {$scope.$apply();}
                //Attempt 2, Getting scope from ref doesnt update $scope.sc object
                var scopeRef = angular.element($("#scopeAnchor")).scope();
                if (!scopeRef.$$phase) { scopeRef.$apply(); }
                // Attempt 3, calling verify function which worked when called from ng-click
                //  but not from here
                $scope.verify();
            });        
    }
});

//Executing this function does update everything as expected
$scope.verify = function () {
    // console.log($scope.sc);
    if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply() }
}
```

Thanks again for any help!

Comment: When you say "Scope Apply doesnt update $scope.sc object" what are you expecting to see?

Comment: `conversation.chatService.state' which is a member of `$scope.sc.conversationsManager.conversations` bindings dont update in HTML Markup unless I call the `$scope.verify()` function. However `$scope.sc.conversationsManager.conversations` itsself does update its bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to trigger the `$scope.$apply()` by broadcasting an event in the callback with `$rootScope.$broadcast('skypeChange');` and then using

```
$scope.$on('skypeChange', function (event) {
            if (!$scope.$$phase) { $scope.$apply() }
        });
```

to trigger the apply. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.